# Align \sim with \overset{}{}

Tags: align

I am trying to align the `\sim` (i.e. `~`) symbols but I cannot get it to work. The problem arises because the first  `\sim` has text on top of it.

This is the two versions of code that I tried out, with the corresponding output.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
y_t &= c + \xi_t, && \xi_t \overset{\text{approx}}{\sim} N(0, \sigma_\xi^2) \\
f_t &= \mu + \eta_t, && \eta_t \sim N(0,\sigma_\eta^2), 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
y_t &= c + \xi_t, && \xi_t &&&\overset{\text{approx}}{\sim} N(0, \sigma_\xi^2) \\
f_t &= \mu + \eta_t, && \eta_t &&&\sim N(0,\sigma_\eta^2), 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why not use `\approx`?

Comment: @HenriMenke To my knowledge that is not standard notation in statistics when it concerns distributions. What I am trying to convey is that this is approximately distributed as '...'. This to me doesn't seem the same as approximately equal to.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\hphantom` helps to get the same width for the second `\sim`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  y_t &= c + \xi_t, & \xi_t
  &\overset{\text{approx}}{\sim} N(0, \sigma_\xi^2)
  \\
  f_t &= \mu + \eta_t, & \eta_t
  &\overset{\hphantom{\text{approx}}}{\sim} N(0,\sigma_\eta^2),
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks a lot! I had already tried `\phantom`, which didn't work in this case, is `\hphantom` the same but then for horizontal spacing?

Comment: @texfan Yes, `\hphantom` only leaves the horizontal space. `\phantom` should have worked, but it also adds the vertical space, unwanted here.

Comment: Thanks! Now I see that `\phantom` works indeed as well. I guess I did something wrong then previously. Thanks again for your help :)!